# Generating multiple files with the same structure

Tags: linux, bash

I want to generate a series of files in which the file name of each file shall be increased by 1 (`File1.txt`, `File2.txt`, `File3.txt`, ... `FileN.txt`) where `N = 250`

Each file has 2 lines.

1. `AAAXXX` (where `XXX = 001` to `250` - automatic increased for each file)
2. `BBBYYY` (where `YYY = 3` digit random number )

Example:

1. File1.txt:

   ```
   AAA001
   BBB175
   ```
2. File5.txt:

   ```
   AAA005
   BBB067
   ```
3. File102.txt:

   ```
   AAA102
   BBB765
   ```

I'm a newbie using Ubuntu Linux 12.04 - but I'm hoping someone can assist.

Comment: Do you just want to do this with a bash shell script ?

Answer (score 3):

You can do it as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in {1..250}
do
    printf "AAA%03d\nBBB%03d" ${i} $(($RANDOM % 1000)) > File${i}.txt
done
```

**Explanation:**

- `for i in {1..250}` - bash way of specifying iteration from 1 to 250, increment size of 1.
- `printf` - shell [printf](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/printf.html) command - used to print formatted string
- `AAA` - string literal (means "exactly as written")
- `%03d` - formatted string, this prints a decimal number padded with 3 zero's in front.
- `\n` - newline
- `BBB` - another string literal
- `%03d` - same as before
- `${i}` - this is the value used in the first formatted string (`%03d`)
- `$(($RANDOM % 1000))` - `$RANDOM` is a system variable that provides a random number for you each time you access it. The `% 1000` to take the modulo so you get a range betwee `0-999`. This is used in the 2nd formatted string (`%03d`)
- `> File${i}.txt`: output redirection; creates and saves to a file (overwrites if file already exists.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a quick one-liner that might start you off:

```
for i in {1..250}; do printf "AAA%03d\nBBB%03d" $i $(($RANDOM % 1000)) > "File${i}.txt"; done
```

Comment: +1 So much better than what I was about to post that I'm secretly ashamed.

Comment: How is $RANDOM 3 digits long?

Comment: I was just getting the OP started.

Comment: @Nick See the `printf` `%03d`, `$RANDOM` will be cropped to 3 digits.

Answer (score 1):

Using bash:

```
for i in {1..250}; do printf "AAA%03d\nBBB%03d\n" "$i" "$((RANDOM%1000))" > "File$i.txt"; done
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write a bash script for this

```
#!/bin/bash      
for (( i=1; i<=250; i++ ))
do
    NUMBER=$[ ( $RANDOM % 999 )  + 100 ]
    echo "AAA$i BBB$NUMBER" > File$i.txt
done
```

Comment: A few problems: 1) This puts `AAA` and `BBB` on the same line; 2) This doesn't give the padding for numbers as required: `AAA5 BBB17`; 3) `$RANDOM % 999` excludes 999 as a random 3-digit candidate; 4) `  + 100` excludes `000 - 099` as random 3-digit candidates.

Comment: Its past midnight here and coffee around, sorry for the mistakes.

Comment: THANKS ALL for your BIG HELP!